# Re-call ajax for update returned data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I've stored on an object an ajax call for to use with deferred

```
this.favorites = $.ajax({
    url: '/get-favorites',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json'
 });
```

when i use `this.favorites.done(myFunction)` in the callback the argument  is an object with required data given from database. If i update my database i need to update at the same time the data given from the ajax call, my idea is to re-run `this.favorite` but I haven't found a method to do this can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: "my idea is to re-run ...". You appear to be seeking that old firm favourite, a Function!

Comment: Yes but if in my function i call `this.favorites.done()`, that is already a function, I don't receive updated data but cached data, like all deferred object, the problem in my case is when I want to receive updated data and not cached data

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking - hence vote to close.

Comment: I think is enough clear, I have already receive a good answer! If you need more clarity read the answer below, if you try my original solution and call 3 times this.favorites.done() you can see that was performed only one call, if you define a property, like suggested in the answer, and for 3 times call this.favorites 3 ajax call was performed. I'm not very able to write in english but I hope you can understand the problem now....

Answer (score 1):

Use a function

```
this.favorites = $.ajax.bind($, {settings})

this.favorites().then(...)
```

or define a property

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'favorites', {
  get:  $.ajax.bind($, {
      url: '/get-favorites',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json'
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Yury Tarabanko, but which is the difference between my definition of favorite and yours? I've try to call 3 times the favorites.get function but only one ajax call was performed because are used the cached data. The solution I've found is to define one update function where is performed another ajax call which  update the data on database and returns the result of operations and the updated data. Thank you very much for the suggestions!

Comment: "which is the difference" my definition will call `$.ajax` every time you access `this.favorites`.

Comment: Your second definition return this error: `Getter must be a function: #<Object>`

Comment: Are you sure? Check `typeof $.ajax.bind($, {
      url: '/get-favorites',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json'
   })` it says it is function. :)

Comment: I mean the `Object.defineProperty(...)` retur the error not `$.ajax.bind(...)`

Comment: The error says that property config is invalid because `get` is not a function. Make sure you are using `$,ajax.bind()` not `$.ajax()`. Kinda totally different things.

Comment: Ok now all work like i need (with .bind() ), great suggestion the `Object.defineProperty(...)`!